# INTERVAL() function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT INTERVAL (33, 5, 10, 15, 25, 27, 34);
```

This query will give the result as 5, because immediate highest value than 33 is found as 34 at index 5.

```
SELECT INTERVAL (33, 5, 10, 15, 25, 27, 33);
```

This query is giving the result as 6.Is this a right answer ? Since there is no integer greater than 33 in the list , it is giving highest index+1 as result or any other logic i am missing?

Please Help me out!
Thanks

Comment: You should actually return a -ve (-1) to indicate NOT_FOUND as no greater number is found

Comment: Are you sure this is mySQL?

Comment: yes Pekka ,You can find in this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval